# Automatically preclude specific records from all find requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a `model` called `Sources` which represent different sets of data in my project.  Users can upload data to a Source.  They can also view a list of available sources and data in those sources.

There's a field I've called `ready` in the `Source model`.  I set that to `0` when an upload begins and when it finishes I set it to `1`.  While data is being uploaded to a specific Source, I don't want that source to be available to users.  So basically any find operation should exclude Sources with `ready=0`.

I can obviously accomplish this by adding `ready=1` to the conditions in every find request in my code, but I'm wondering if there's something I can do that's a bit more elegant and simple so that records with `ready=0` are automatically omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Rails' `default_scope` method:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class

You can set the default scope of a model and it will be applied automatically to all queries using ActiveRecord

Comment: Yeah that's something I should probably know about :).  Thanks!